# CurrentValueSubject: ignore the first value on subscribe and trigger update only if there is already a value

Tags: ios, swift, combine, publisher, currentvaluesubject

Code:

```
private var _nwPathStatusSubject: CurrentValueSubject<NWPath.Status, Never> = .init(.satisfied)
private var networkPathStatusPublisher: AnyPublisher<NWPath.Status, Never> {
    _nwPathStatusSubject
        .removeDuplicates()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

    networkStatusCancellable = networkPathStatusPublisher
        .sink {[weak self] newStatus in
            print(newStatus)
        }
```

The moment I subscribe to the `networkPathStatusPublisher` I get notified in the `.sink {[weak self] newStatus in`

I'd like to ignore the current/first value on subscription and only make the further event to trigger the execution of the `sink`.

Comment: You should use PassThroughSubject. If you wish to stick with CurrentValueSubject then use `.dropFirst()`

Comment: Actually, I've ended up using `PassThroughSubject`